# replace channel while iterating

Tags: go, channel

I want to replace the channel with a new one under some condition, for example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func subMsg(s string) chan string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
        for range ticker.C {
            ch <- s
        }
    }()

    return ch
}

func main() {
    chStr := subMsg("hello")

    go func() {
        i := 0
        for s := range chStr {
            log.Print(s)
            i++
            if i > 5 {
                log.Print("new topic")
                i = 0

                chStr = subMsg("world")
            }
        }
    }()

    select {}
}
```

I expect this code snippet outputs 5 "hello", then "world", but it didn't work this way. I am not very clear about what happened when I re-assign a channel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `for range`, and per [Spec: For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) the range expression is only evaluated once.

> The range expression `x` is evaluated once before beginning the loop, with one exception: if at most one iteration variable is present and `len(x)` is [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity), the range expression is not evaluated.

The `chStr` variable is not checked by the `for` loop later on, so changing its value has no effect.

You can't use `for range` if you want to switch over to another channel.

Simply use a "normal" loop and receive from the channel inside it. Use the special form `x, ok := <-ch` so you know when the channel is closed, and so you can break from the loop (to mimic the `for range` working):

```
for {
    s, ok := <-chStr
    if !ok {
        break
    }
    log.Print(s)
    i++
    if i > 5 {
        log.Print("new topic")
        i = 0

        chStr = subMsg("world")
    }
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/J0q3ssvpguS).